Why has external monitor stopped working over USB-C hub after Windows update?
I have Lenovo p14s and Dell S3221QS. Before the Windows 11, version 23H2 update, monitor was connected through HDMI to HDMI in a 6-1 Anker USB-C hub (AK-A83650A1).
After the last Windows update monitor stopped working with a hub, and now it can be only connected with a HDMI-USB-C cable directly to the laptop.
I tested new hubs (new one AK-A83650A1 and new Anker 332 5-1 / A8355), where I connected the monitor with both of HDMI-HDMI and HDMI-USB-C. No success, only a direct connection to laptop with USB-C.
What is here happen? Maybe can somebody recommend an hub, which would work with my hardware?
